# How to recover a list of geoposition from a site that use Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to make an application that contains a lot of different restaurant in a local database to help people find restaurant next to their location.

I would like to add the french bakery Paul:
http://www.paul.fr/shop/fr-FR/Shops

I have found out that it uses the CreateMarker() function to display markers from a list of point but I do not know where is the file that contains the different bakery with their latitude/longitude: http://www.paul.fr/uploads/script/google.map.js

Is there a way to obtain a list of what I am looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is loaded via an AJAX request. The requested URL is http://www.paul.fr/shop/fr-FR/CMSMS/shops. You can see this in the `init` function of the Google Map. In the JSON file, you will find the geocoordinates in the `AddressLatitude` and `AddressLongitude` fields.

Answer (score 1):

It is ajax requesting "/shop/fr-FR/CMSMS/shops" , which is returning json containing points i assume. I've copied the json to [here](http://tny.cz/e3d4d4be). Put it in a file and ajax request then JSON parse it. The data you need is actually in the AddressLatitude and AddressLongitude properties of each entry. You may use [this](http://www.ist.rit.edu/~jxs/services/JSON/) site to explore the returned JSON and understand how it works, or just use the CreateMarker function they're using.